# MIPS: Printing string with no pseduo instructions

Tags: string, assembly, mips, cpu-registers

Below I have

```
.globl main
.data
prompt:
        .asciiz  "Hello world!"
.text
main:
    addi $v0, $v0, 4
    lui $a0, 0x1000
    syscall
rtn:
    jr $ra
```

Now, I'm not sure why the string is not printing, it runs without syntax errors. Also, I am not permitted to use any pseudo-instructions, so that is why I am doing this the slightly longer way. That is where the error is coming in, I do not know where the prompt string is being stored? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that `prompt` is located at address `0x1000` ?

Comment: In examples we were given in class, he would create an array which he did not define to start at any given address. Then he created a string and called it prompt. When he wanted to use prompt, he added 10 to 0x1000 to get to the first index out of the array (the array was 10 bytes long). The next thing was prompt, which was a0 + 10.

Comment: OK - even if it's the right address you should probably get into the habit of using the symbolic address rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: Are you doing this using SPIM?

Comment: Yes, I am using SPIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SPIM, the `.data` section starts at address 0x10010000 by default. So to print the Hello World string without using pseudo-instructions you could use this:

```
.globl main
.data
prompt:
    .asciiz  "Hello world!"
.text
main:
    addi $v0, $zero, 4
    lui $a0, 0x1001       # $a0 = 0x10010000
    syscall
rtn:
    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the address is 0x1000, that means the upper 16 bits are all zero, and the bottom 16 bits are 0x1000. You are loading the upper 16 bits. So instead of `lui $a0, 0x1000` try `addiu $a0, $0, 0x1000`

However, your assembler's symbol manipulation expressions shouldn't count as pseudo-instructions, so something like this GAS code (or the equivalent in your assembler) should also be allowed:

```
lui $a0, %hi(prompt)
ori $a0, $a0, %lo(prompt)
```